# SQL Server View with errors still work?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a following code saved as View

```
CREATE VIEW uvw_AllProductInOrder
AS  
    SELECT DISTINCT I.OrderId, O.OrderNumber, O.OrderDate,
        STUFF((
        SELECT  ',' + CAST(I2.ProductId AS varchar)
        FROM OrderItem AS I2
        WHERE I2.OrderId = I.OrderId
        FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')  AS ProductList,
        SUM(I.Quantity * I.UnitPrice) OVER (PARTITION BY OrderId) AS TotalAmount
    FROM OrderItem AS I 
    INNER JOIN [Order] AS O ON I.OrderId = O.Id
GO
```

When ever i open it in design view, i always get the following errors:

> Error in WHERE clause near '(' .Unable to parse query text

But the query is **SAVED** and **DOES** return correct result when execute.
Should I ignore what design view say?

Comment: Right click on the view in object explorer and select script to new window as alter. Then run it with F5. If there are no problems then yes ignore design view. In fact you should get out of the habit of using it

Answer (score 1):

It Ok,

Design view not able to parse windows function, xml conversion and stuff.
It will work fine.